# I'm from a non-engineering background, how do I make sense of signal processing?

Tags: regression, signal-processing

I know linear regression, $l_1$ regularization etc in statistics. How is the problem being studied in compressed sensing/signal processing different from that in statistics/linear regression (estimating coefficients of linear model)?

From the book A mathematical introduction to compressive sensing http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817649470, "observed $y$ is connected to signal via $Ax=y$, where $A$ is 'measurement matrix'. My question will be, for example, is this matrix $A$ customary? If your answer can include, for example how cellphone works and how signal processing works in this process etc. that'd be cool.

Comment: Too broad of a question for a site like this. ($A$ is just a linear operator and can be composed of any of a number of things.) My advice is to just keep reading. If you have trouble with a specific topic/issue/problem in the future, then please do post them.

Comment: Can you make a explanation of $A$ an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{A}$ is an arbitrary linear operator. It can be composed of FFTs, resamplings, any linear filter, subbanding, data corruption/loss, change of basis, decimation, etc. Basically anything that you can represent with a matrix (which is just a linear system by definition). For example, suppose that your input signal has 5 samples but the second and third ones got corrupted/lost somehow, then

$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_0 \\ x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\x_4
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_0 \\ x_3 \\x_4
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Keep in mind that the product of any two linear operators is also a linear operator, so basic individual operators can be chained together to form more complex ones.

Comment: If I'm interpreting correctly, in your example a input signal $x$ is a sequence of 5 numbers. $y$ is what you observed through selective sampling, and matrix $A$ represents the sampling process. So the processing system transforms $x$ into $y$, despite $x$ itself is not observable. Given a transformation method $A$, compressive sensing is to infer these signals $x$ from observed $y$'s. Am I correct?

Comment: So this is like a generalization of linear regression

Comment: @monotonic Yes, the idea is to estimate $x$ from the observed $y$. Compressive sensing, however, deals with the specific case of $A$ being underdetermined, i.e., you have fewer observations than you do unknowns (hence the term "compressive"). I wouldn't say that it is a generalization of linear regression; linear regression is a specific case of fitting observables to a linear model, which in the simplest case is just finding the least squares estimate of $x$ when $A$ is overdetermined. A lot of the work in CS is designing $A$ to get a good estimate of $x$, e.g.,  you want $y$ to be sparse.

Comment: I watched some signal processing videos. Signal $x(t)$ can be transformed by a system $A$ and output a function $y(t)$. So here we're doing the reverse way, we're estimating $x(t)$ from $y(t)$ and $A$. Am I correct?

Comment: @monotonic Yes. Also, the comment I made previously about wanting $y$ to be sparse in CS is wrong. What you actually want is $x$ to be sparse, which is what makes finding the correct solution of an underdetermined system possible.